# List in Python and Concatenate it

Tags: python

[guys I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xrDX.png)Hi guys I want to use \n in the list how can I use it for example :

```
from termcolor2 import colored

flag = True
usercount = 0
adminlist = []
while flag:
    name1 = input("enter user name:")
    family1 = input("enter user family:")
    usercount += 1
    print("hi",colored(name1,"blue"),colored(family1,"blue"),f"welcome to our group\nuser count:",colored(usercount,"green"))
     adminlist.append(name1)
     adminlist.appedn(fname1)
     print(adminlist)
    shure = input("conn or exit?")
    if shure == "exit":
        print(colored("Admin loged out",'red'))
        break
    if shure == "conn":
        print(colored("enter your new user:",'green'))
    else:
        print("ERROR! SOMTHING WENT WRONG!")
          break
```

[my code return it but I wanna all admins goes to the list like this
[mmdyari , saraazadkhani]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSjOf.png)

but it returns all admins in one list and separate name1 and fname1 how can I Concatenate this and for the next input it puts into the list

Comment: fix your indentation please. And post the actual code that's causing the problem. This one can't even run.

Comment: you will have to fix indentation and typos first.

Comment: Are you asking how to format your list when printing? If so, then show how you'd like the list to be printed.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel
 enter user name:mmd
enter user family:yari
hi mmd yari welcome to our group
user count: 1
['mmd', 'yari']
conn or exit?conn
enter your new user:
enter user name:sara
enter user family:azd
hi sara azd welcome to our group
user count: 2
['mmd', 'yari', 'sara', 'azd']
conn or exit?








but all inputs get into one list

Comment: I meant for you to edit your question. Adding details in a comment is not helpful as formatting is limited in comments.

Comment: @njzk2 no sir it run but all inputs goes to a list like this ["Alex","jhonson","all","heydari"]
but I want to separate all admins!

Comment: @JustinEzequiel sorry Can you check the image?

Comment: The output you see is the string representation of a list. If you want to print it out differently, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: You've shown how it appears now but you haven't shown how you *want* it to appear.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Can you check it again?

Comment: @MmDYi it doesn't. indentation is wrong, and `fname1` is not declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Code-Apprentice said, what you are seeing is the representation of your list.
If you want to format your list, you'll have to do it yourself, e.g.,

```py
arr = ["Alex","jhonson","all","heydari"]
for i in range(0, len(arr), 2):
    print(arr[i], arr[i+1])
```

which outputs

```
Alex jhonson
all heydari
```

but it would be better to change your list thus

```
better = [("Alex","jhonson"),("all","heydari")]
for firstname, lastname in better:
    print(firstname, lastname)
```

which also outputs

```
Alex jhonson
all heydari
```

but is much clearer.

If you only want to print each name pair separately, then why are you printing the entire list everytime?
What's stopping you from just printing the current pair? E.g.,

```
print(name1, family1)
```

or, if you really want the square brackets and the quotes

```
print([name1, family1])
```